# objective c dynamic object creation

Tags: objective-c, class, creation

Quick question for you.  I want to be able to create an instance of an object.  The object type is based of a string.

In php you can just replace the class name with a string, but I doubt it is that easy in Objective c.

```
NSString * className;
id theObject;
className = @"TestObject";
theObject = [[className alloc] init];
```

here is a break down of what it might look like.  I want to try and avoid using a giant case style statement.

Is it possible to use the selector system for this?

any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a class by its name using one of the following obj-c runtime functions (you may need to import  header:

```
id objc_lookUpClass(const char *name)
id objc_getClass(const char *name)
```

So your code may look like (have not tested it though):

```
NSString * className = @"TestObject";
id theObject = nil;
Class myClass = objc_lookUpClass([className UTF8String]);
if (myClass)
   theObject = [[myClass alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 30):

You can get a `Class` object dynamically with `NSClassFromString()`

```
Class c = NSClassFromString(@"ClassName");
id obj = [[c alloc] init];
```

Comment: Without a doubt this community is the best.  Thank you.  That worked like a charm