# How to dynamically load class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, classloader

how to dynamically load a class in Objective-C? As per my need, class name will be in a text file, which i need to read it, and then load the class dynamically ...

This code is loading a class in Java... I want the same functionality to be done in Objective-C...

```
public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    ClassLoader classLoader = MainClass.class.getClassLoader();

    try {
        Class aClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.jenkov.MyClass");
        System.out.println("aClass.getName() = " + aClass.getName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

which function in Objective-C is used instead of loadClass() in Java?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175547/objective-c-dynamic-object-creation/2175616

Comment: not a duplicate the other question asks how to create a instance from a class already loaded - this asks how to load from disk

Comment: hey.. my main point here is, how to load a class dynamically inObjective-C??