# Insert a new line of code for logging a method during runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, reflection

I want to add code in an existing method during runtime in Objective-C. Is this possible? I checked for reflection in Objective-C, but it has API for adding a class or a method, and modifying a method selector. But I just want to insert code during runtime.

Comment: Are you asking if you can - while your app is running - type a line of code into a text field, and then have your app compile and execute that code?

Comment: Be more specific about what your desired outcome is.

Comment: I have an existing project. I wanted to add Logs into every method and when Every method is called I want to write that in a log file. I don't want to add a new line of code manually in every method. I am trying to check if there are possibility to add a line of code in every method in the project during run time.

Comment: [ObjC track all method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7223555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198840/how-to-dynamically-load-class-in-objective-c) load classes at runtime. You can't just insert some code during runtime.